# Precompile Load and Transform xml/sef files with client SaxonJS2.6

Tags: javascript, xslt-2.0, saxon-js

Try to display some .xml data file through a .sef.json transformed file (initially .xsl file) with SaxonJS 2.6 (SaxonJS26.rt.js/SaxonJS26.js); got two valid .xml and .sef.json files respectively
The index.html file is as follows:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>SxnTrnsct</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../saxon-js2.6/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sxn_tscrpt.js" ></script> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Smthn ..</h2>
  <div id="output"></div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

and that "sxn_tscrpt.js" goes like this:

```
"use strict"
var opts = {styleSheetLocation:"../xml/htrnsctstl.sef.json",sourceLocation:"../xml/trnsct.xml"}
onload = function()
    {
    SaxonJS.transform(opts,"async")
}
```

My os platform is windows 8/10, webserver is IIS, my CLIENT SaxonJS is 2.6 and the .sef file produced, has been generated through that xslt3 node.js module (for sure, the generated .sef.json file is valid, although understood could be certain escaping characters issues ...)
Don't know what other "under the scene" details should be provided ...
Anyway, the following opera browser errors were issued when launched that index.html (localhost):

```
SaxonJS2.rt.js:1113 Uncaught (in promise) XError: **No stylesheet supplied**
    at Object.transform (SaxonJS2.rt.js:1113:178)
    at onload (sxn_tscrpt.js:9:17)SaxonJS2.rt.js:772
GET http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/trnsct.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

These sort of problems has already been risen .. but ain't find nowhere a real, clear and reliable solution ..

If this very simple stuff could't be fixed, how one would expect of even work with SaxonJS (2.5 .. 2.6 .. ) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think you need `stylesheetLocation` and not `styleSheetLocation`.

Documentation in https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!starting/installing and https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/transform confirms that.

Comment: Just about the same stuff:
SaxonJS2.rt.js:772 GET http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/htrnsctstl.sef.json 404 (Not Found)

SaxonJS2.rt.js:772 GET http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/trnsct.xml 404 (Not Found)
.....
SaxonJS2.rt.js:1113 Uncaught (in promise) XError: Failed to read JSON input http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/htrnsctstl.sef.json: XError:Failed to read http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/htrnsctstl.sef.json(Not Found: http://localhost/mbPrct/xml/htrnsctstl.sef.json); code:SXJS0006
    at SaxonJS2.rt.js:1113:84
    at async Promise.all (index 0
Clear up browser cache couple of times ..
Don't really knw

Comment: @mirexS, consider to accept the answer then so that your question shown as resolved.

Comment: sorry, only now checked ..